# Update Array and preserve data

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to update a Global Array that contain 24 data

```
Decimal[] GolbalInfo = new Decimal[24];
```

with three different small array containing each one 8 data

```
Decimal[] TableSwInfo ;
```

how can i do it please ?

Comment: If you update a value in the `GlobalInfo` array, do you want it to be updated in the corresponding `TableSwinfo` array as well automatically?

Comment: @Anders Abel i wnat a methode like Redim.Preserve in vb !!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post some code.  This is a relatively simple question, but you should at least show that you've done some effort on your part.

Comment: i have tried first to fill the small table with data by    TableSwInfo = new Decimal[4] { receivedEvent.tagData.can_Msg.data[4].... and after that i have tried to fill global array with this data from the small array with GolbalInfo = TableSwInfo; but the info in Global array are cleared once i try to fill it by the second table

Comment: Use a `List<T>` instead. BTW there is no "global" stuff in C#. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CopyTo`. Assuming you have arrays like the following:

```
//main destination array
Decimal[] GolbalInfo = new Decimal[24];

//smaller source arrays
Decimal[] SmallOne = new Decimal[8];
Decimal[] SmallTwo = new Decimal[8];
Decimal[] SmallThree = new Decimal[8];
```

You can set the large one using the smaller ones like this:

```
SmallOne.CopyTo(GolbalInfo, 0);//sets 0 - 7
SmallTwo.CopyTo(GolbalInfo, 7);//sets 8 - 15
SmallThree.CopyTo(GolbalInfo, 15);//sets 16 - 23
```

I would recommend that you validate the sizes before adding them, although it may be a safe assumption depending on your setup

Comment: thank you thats working ;) what is muse any way :D